# How can I perform Playfair cypher in the text "Tattoo"?

Tags: python, encryption

I have a word "Tattoo" and key is "EGYPT VICTORY", how I perform Playfair cypher in this text?
I didn't find the rule for double letter in same word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tattoo would be split to "TA TX TO OX." Double letter occurrences that align to pairs are padded with 'X'. If there is an uneven number of letters, then an 'X' is padded to the end of the string. Reference: http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/playfair.php

Code:

```
def prepare_text(txt):
   i = 0
   while 2*i + 1 < len(txt):
     if txt[2*i] == txt[2*i + 1]:
         txt = txt[0:2*i + 1] + "X" + txt[2*i + 1:]
     i += 1
   return txt
```